# De-referencing a pointer and assigning it a variable instantly resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I wanted to assign a variable's address to a pointer by de-referencing it. Why is it giving a segmentation fault? I expected the program to print address of u variable.

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main(){
       int t = 4;
       int u = 5;
       int * p;
       *p = &t;
       *p = u;
       cout << p;
  }
```

Comment: `*p = &t;` is wrong. Turn up the warning level on your compiler. That needs to be `p = &t;`.

Comment: Voting to close for typo.

Comment: [It works fine after you fixed the typo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tj9dro9VSzZzmAUq) Are you sure that you *re-compiled* it?

Comment: Please copy and paste that actual code that gives you the segfault, after you make it an [mcve] of course

Comment: it's saying, you are probably allocating too much memory or producing too much output

Comment: try on geeksforgeeks ide it's showing that error message

Comment: @KUMARGAURAV I would avoid geeksforgeeks compile.  Use coliru and you will see that it compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d530ddedbdcc7b2

Comment: Should we delete this now that the question has been changed to the correct code. Or should we edit it back to the original error so that the answer makes sense?

Comment: Rolled back. Editing a question after you got an answer is against the rules if the edit leaves the answer without context.

Answer (score 1):

Use `p = &t;` to assign the address to p. p is already a pointer. Or do it on the same line with `int *p = &t`

Comment: On geeksforgeeks ide its showing error